# Integration by substitution in a special case, "inverting" the interval

Tags: calculus

By letting $y=a-x$, show that $$\int_0^{a}f(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(a-x)\,dx $$ Can someone help me to solve this question .This is only the first part of the question. We have to use this proof to do the second part.

Comment: did you actually try to substitute $y$ for $a-x$? What do you obtain? Which are the new limits of the integral?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with following the advice? We use integration by substitution, if $y = a-x$, we have $dy = -dx$, and for $x = 0$ we have $y = a$ and $x = a$ gives $y = 0$, so
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^a f(x-a)\, dx &= \int_a^0 f(y)\,\, ({-}dy)\\
     &= -\int_a^0 f(y)\, dy\\
     &= \int_0^a f(y)\, dy\\
     &= \int_0^a f(x)\, dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: I have got it I have shown that both \int_0^{a}f(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(a-x)\,dx and \int_0^{a}f(x)\,dx = \int_0^a f(a-x)\,dx =f(a)-f(0)

Answer (score 0):

you change variable, let u = a -x :
$$
du = d(a-x) = -dx \\
x = a-u
$$
$$
\int_{x = 0}^{x=a}f(x)dx = \int_{a-u = 0}^{a-u=a}f(a-u)(-du)
$$
$$
= \int_{u=0}^{u=a}f(a-u)du
$$